# is there a google polymer element / integration for azure adal?

Tags: adal

Is there a polymer webcomponent element integration for Azure ADAL ?

In my polymer project once I add bower components all I get is the adal-angular. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. Please enter an idea in Uservoice, so that we can add it to the backlog! https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory